# Can i setup external users to use forms developed using Powerapps

Tags: powerapp

I need a prompt answer to this please

Would i be able to setup external users to use forms developed using Powerapps?
We have a standard business license (Office 365)
If someone can shed some light that would be really great.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Kindly check this out : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKl4nLL4tcQ

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/share-app-guests

Answer (score 3):

As of October 2019 we are able to share our Power Apps with external users. The users must be guest users in your tenants Azure AD. They must also have license to use Power Apps – in your tenant or at their home tenant.